# regex function that matches all occurrences of term R

Tags: r, regex

... this regex function is supposed to match all occurrences of this format:

`c.1244a>a`

but it returns just the first occurrence.

This is the regex function

```
("(g|c|m|r|p).[0-9]*-[0-9]*del")

a <- "fjfjvjg , c.2587a>f lfkfgg, vk dldC g.2547b>m"
stringr::str_extract(a, ("(g|c|m|r|p).[0-9]*[a-z]>[a-z]"))
```

Comment: Try `stringr::str_extract_all()` instead. `str_extract` only grabs the first one.

Comment: Instead of `(g|c|m|r|p)` why not just `[gcmrp]`? Not going to solve your problem but it just makes more sense. Also, you need to escape your period `\.`

Comment: Davis, double escape for R on the period `\\.` but yes.

Comment: And per your edit, it may be better to write a second regex expression to match the second pattern. There's no reason to get super clever with a really complicated pattern to match both, when you can just match one first, then the toher

Comment: `[gcmrp]\\.\\d{4}-\\d{4}[a-z]{3}` or similar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use pattern:

```
[gcmrp]\\.\\d{4}[a-z>0-9-]+
```

- `[gcmrp]` Character set for letters `gcmrp`.
- `\\.\\d{4}` A full stop followed by four digits.
- `[a-z>0-9-]+` Character set for lower case letters, digits, `>` and `-`.

You can try it [here](http://rextester.com/VFYRHE59241).

---

In r:

```
a <- "fjfjvjg , c.2587a>f lfkfgg, vk dldC g.2547b>m c.1244-2145del"
stringr::str_extract_all(a, ("[gcmrp]\\.\\d{4}[a-z>0-9-]+"))
```

Prints:

```
[1] "c.2587a>f"      "g.2547b>m"      "c.1244-2145del"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this solution:

```
a <- "fjfjvjg , c.2587a>f lfkfgg, vk dldC g.2547b>m"
stringr::str_extract_all(a, ("[gcmrp]\\.[0-9]*[a-z]>[a-z]"))[[1]]

[1] "c.2587a>f" "g.2547b>m"
```